# MySQL using Temp Tables (Learning)

Tags: mysql

I am currently learning SQL in order to make a simple RFM report from our Magento Database, I can currently do this by exporting two queries and pasting them into a Excel template, I'd like to get rid of the Excel template.

I thought creating a temporary table to hold data of the past 6 months would give understanding if buying patterns were changing (To show customers that we're losing).

```
     CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Months_RFM_6
     SELECT
     customer_email,
     count(*) AS Order_Count,
     MAX(created_at) as Last_Order_Date,
     MIN(created_at) as First_Order_Date,
     SUM(base_total_paid) AS Total_Lifetime_Sales,
     (SUM(base_total_paid) / count(*)) AS AOV,
     SUM(base_total_offline_refunded + base_total_online_refunded) AS Refund_Total,
     AVG(total_qty_ordered) AS UPO
     FROM
     mage_sales_order AS o
     WHERE
     o.created_at > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
    GROUP BY
    customer_email
    ORDER BY
    count(*) DESC,

    SELECT
    customer_email,
    count(*) AS Order_Count,
    MAX(created_at) as Last_Order_Date,
    MIN(created_at) as First_Order_Date,
    SUM(base_total_paid) AS Total_Lifetime_Sales,
    SUM(base_total_paid) / count(*)) AS AOV,
    SUM(base_total_offline_refunded + base_total_online_refunded) AS Refund_Total,
    AVG(total_qty_ordered) AS UPO
    FROM
    mage_sales_order AS o
    GROUP BY
    customer_email
    ORDER BY
    count(*) DESC
```

I'm sure it's a problem with the syntax between the temporary table and the SQL query. I am not adding the temporary table to the query yet till I can get it working, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created the temp table the content is based on the select result using in select so you should just use a select * from the temp table for see the result  eg:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Months_RFM_6
SELECT customer_email,
count(*) AS Order_Count,
MAX(created_at) as Last_Order_Date,
MIN(created_at) as First_Order_Date,
SUM(base_total_paid) AS Total_Lifetime_Sales,
(SUM(base_total_paid) / count(*)) AS AOV,
SUM(base_total_offline_refunded + base_total_online_refunded) AS Refund_Total,
AVG(total_qty_ordered) AS UPO
FROM mage_sales_order 
WHERE mage_sales_order.created_at > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
GROUP BY customer_email
ORDER BY  Order_Count DESC
;

select * from Months_RFM_6
```

Comment: I ran this through [link](https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/) and it seems that the select link is wrong with syntax. I've tried the query and it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: Error comes from not existing alias after: FROM mage_sales_order AS